# String formatting of a Double

Tags: string-formatting, swift

I can't seem to find a way to format a Double limiting the precision to just a couple of positions after the decimal point when presenting that in a label.
Maybe I'm missing something major, but I couldn't find anything in the official documentation.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: By the way, I would prefer `NSNumberFormatter`, which honors the device's `locale`. Thus `let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()`, set `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` to however many digits you want, and then you can do `let string = formatter.stringFromNumber(3.1415)`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There's no way to do this using `String` interpolation.

You can find a good discussion about this on [this Apple Dev Forum post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/973494).

You can use `NSNumberFormatter` or `NSDateFormatter` to format the output.

Alternatively, to use `printf`-like syntax, you can still use `NSString`:

```
var str = NSString(format: "Hello, world %.2f", 42.12312312313)
```

Comment: FYI, your link appears to have experienced linkrot.

Comment: **Swift5** String(format: "%.2f", arguments: [count])

Answer (score 33):

Unsure if there is a pure Swift-way but you can always use NSStrings `+stringWithFormat:`:

```
let str = String(format: "%.2f", 1.23)
```

Comment: For something as simple as this example, this is a perfectly good solution.

Comment: You may use String not NSString : let str = String(format: "%.2f", 1.23)