# How to use println in Swift to format number

Tags: swift, println, nsformatter

When logging-out a float in Objective-C you can do the following to limit your output to only 2 decimal places:

```
float avgTemp = 66.844322156
NSLog (@"average temp. = %.2f", avgTemp);
```

But how do you do this in Swift?
And how do you escape other characters in `println` in Swift?

Here's a regular Swift `println` statement:

```
println ("Avg. temp = \(avgTemp)")
```

So how do you limit decimal places?

Also, how do you escape double-quotes in `println`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precision String Format Specifier In Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift)

Comment: possible duplicate of [String formatting of a Double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047374/string-formatting-of-a-double)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's the shortest solution I found thus far:

```
let avgTemp = 66.844322156
println(NSString(format:"%.2f", avgTemp))
```

Its like the swift version of NSString's `stringWithFormat`

Comment: println is removed in 2.0, use print instead

Answer (score 11):

Everything about the format of a number as a string can be adjusted using a NSNumberFormatter:

```
let nf = NSNumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2
println(nf.stringFromNumber(0.33333)) // prints 0.33
```

You can escape quotes with a backslash

```
println("\"God is dead\" -Nietzsche")
```

Comment: seems like a lot of work compared to using `%.2f` in Objective-C

Comment: Yeah, I agree. There's definitely ways to make it more efficient such as with an extension, but it's still messy.

Comment: Agreed. There MUST be a simpler basic format string approach.

Comment: since Swift is still in beta, maybe inline string formatters haven't been implemented yet

Comment: The \\() notation literally accesses the description property of whatever value is inside it. It would be cool to have the ability to include other formatting arguments but for now at least that would all have to be done manually.

Answer (score 8):

> Println() is deprecated.

```
 var avgTemp = 66.844322156
  print("average temp. = (round(avgTemp*100)/100)")   // average temp. = 66.84
```

//or

print(NSString(format:"average temp. = %.2f", avgTemp))) // average temp. = 66.84 
 avgTemp = 66.846322156

print(String(format:"average temp. = %.2f", avgTemp))  // average temp. = 66.85

Comment: You have to put slash (\\) before the "(round(avgTemp*100)/100)" to make it works.  
Like this:  
<code>print("average temp. = \\(round(avgTemp*100)/100)")</code>

Answer (score 0):

If you need to print floating point numbers often with a certain precision, you could extend Float and Double with convenience methods.  For example, for 2 significant figure precision:

```
// get Float or Double with 2 significant figure precision
var numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
extension Float {
    var sf2:String {
        get {
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
            numberFormatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 2
            return numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(self)!
        }
    }
}
extension Double {
    var sf2:String {
        get {
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
            numberFormatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 2
            return numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(self)!
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you need to print things:

```
let x = 5.23325
print("The value of x is \(x.sf2)")
```