# If minutes are < 9 add a 0 before it

Tags: swift, date

with this code you can save the current time but if the Minutes < 9 than it gives you the time in 5:9 instead of 5:09. How can you fix this?

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let Tijd = "\(hour) : \(minutes)"
```

Comment: Use a date formatter with an appropriately configured date format. Don't write this date to string conversion yourself. Most people don't right dates/times as you do. You can't forget about internationalization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift number formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167453/swift-number-formatting)

Comment: The question I cited shows how to get strings in general to print out with leading zeroes or taking up a certain amount of space.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two choices.

1. Use a `String(format:)`

   ```
   let date = Date()
   let calendar = Calendar.current
   let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
   let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
   let tijd = String(format:"%d:%02d", hour, minutes) // change to "%02d:%02d" if you also want the hour to be 2-digits.
   ```
2. Use `DateFormatter`.

   ```
   let date = Date()
   let df = DateFormatter()
   df.dateFormat = "H:mm" // Use "HH:mm" if you also what the hour to be 2-digits
   let tijd = df.string(from: date)
   ```

Comment: DateFormatter FTW

Answer (score 0):

A solution for SwiftUi:

```
let date = Date()

Text(date, style: .time) // January 8, 2023
Text(date, style: .date) // 12:08 PM
```