# Convert float value to String in Swift

Tags: swift

I want to convert -33.861382,151.210316,226.76 to String. I tried to type cast it but was unscucessful. 
How to convert float value to String ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Precision String Format Specifier In Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift)

Comment: possible duplicate of [String formatting of a Double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047374/string-formatting-of-a-double)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you want some more control of how it's converted you can either use `+stringWithFormat` on `NSString` or `NSNumberFormatter`

```
let f = -33.861382
let s = NSString(format: "%.2f", f)

let nf = NSNumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
// Configure the number formatter to your liking
let s2 = nf.stringFromNumber(f)
```

Comment: NSNumberFormatter is the way to go, because it's locale aware. Not every country uses the 12.345 format.

Answer (score 44):

Using Xcode 6.3 you can convert a float to a string using .description

```
var float = -33.861382
var string = "my float is " + float.description
```

or you could let swift do it for you using:

```
var string = "my float is \(float)"
```

Answer (score 25):

In swift 3 it is simple as given below

```
let stringFloat =  String(describing: float)
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple example in Swift 3.0 for convert your `NSNumber` into String with decimal using `NumberFormatter` and if you want to know more about formatter then [link here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

```
let num = NSNumber(value: 8.800000000000001)
let formatter : NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
let str = formatter.string(from: num)!
print(str)
```

**Output :**

```
8.8
```

Any query according to my code then put comment.

Answer (score -4):

Directly from page 6 of the swift programming reference available from developer.apple.com:

Values are never implicitly converted to another type. If you need to convert a value to a different type, explicitly make an instance of the desired type.

```
let label = "The width is "
let width = 94
let widthLabel = label + String(width)
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

OR

There’s an even simpler way to include values in strings: Write the value in parentheses, and write a backslash () before the parentheses. For example:

```
let apples = 3
let oranges = 5
let appleSummary = "I have \(apples) apples."
let fruitSummary = "I have \(apples + oranges) pieces of fruit."
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l

Comment: OP asked for Float -> String not Int -> String. The first solution you gave with `String(width)` does not work with Float.

Comment: =)))))))))))))))))))))