# XCode Swift: label.text = float?

Tags: ios, swift, numbers, label

I know this might be a simple question but I didn't find an answer for Swift: How can I display a `Float` variable in a label. I get the error: "`Float` is not convertible to `String`".

I don't want to convert the float into string because I want to calculate with it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123312/convert-float-value-to-string-in-swift

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can do it in several ways.

Method 1:

`lable.text = "\(float)"`

Method 2:

`lable.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", f)`

Method 3:

`let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
 numberFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
 lable.text = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(f)`

Method 4:

Starting from Xcode 6.3, we can use float.description to get string value

`lable.text = float.description`

Answer (score 1):

```
label.text = "\(floatvariable)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `NSNumberFormatter` if you want more control over the number formatting:

```
let nf = NSNumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
nf.maximumFractionDigits = 2
label.text = nf.stringFromNumber(floatvariable)
```