# Doubles to Strings swift

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, double, implicit-conversion

I am trying to convert a double, `value` to a string. This string will be set as the text of a Cocoa Touch UI element, that only accepts strings (I can't use the double as-is)

```
let value = example double value (my actual code is not this)
UIElementBeingSet.text = NSString(value)
```

When I try the above code, I get "Use of unresolved identifier 'value'.

Through my research, I have found questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047374/string-formatting-of-a-double), which seem to be asking similar things, but that question and similar ones involve limiting precision, don't involve UI elememts (which I am asking about), and are just overall not the answers I need.

Sorry for a basic question, and thanks!

Comment: For a lot more info on string formatting, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051314/precision-string-format-specifier-in-swift/24052438#24052438)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use standard string formatting use `format`:

```
let d = 1.0 / 3.0
let s = String(format: "%0.3f", d)
println("s: \(s)")
```

Output:

> s: 0.333

or

```
let s = String(format: "%0.16f", d)
println("s: \(s)")
```

Output:

> s: 0.3333333333333333

String interpolation does not allow any control over the presentation, it is good for logging but severly lacking for presentation to a user.

Answer (score 1):

Use string interpolation:

```
let d: Double = 1 / 3
let x = "\(d)"
```

If you try that in a playground, it will print:

```
"0.333333333333333"
```

Read more about [string interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_430)