# how to send user longitude and latitude coordinates through sms text

Tags: xcode, swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller, cllocationcoordinate2d

Within my "share location" function, I want the user to have the ability to send a text that shares their current location in the form of long/lat coordinates. The error I get with what I have implemented is "Contextual type "string" cannot be used with array literal". How or what is the correct code to implement?

Here's my code

```
 @IBAction func shareLocation(sender: AnyObject) {
   // Send user coordinates through text

    if !MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
        print("SMS services are not available")

        var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D

        messageVC!.body = [coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
        messageVC!.recipients = [LookoutCell.description()];
        messageVC!.messageComposeDelegate = self;


        self.presentViewController(messageVC!, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with this code:

1. You're checking if you can't send a text via `!MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()`, and then sending if you can't (brackets need to end earlier)
2. You declare `var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D` without value, which won't compile
3. Latitude and longitude are doubles, so you need string formatting to output these values
4. `body` is a String, you were trying to send it an array.
5. Try this instead: `messageVC!.body = String(format: "Lat: %.4f, Long: %.4f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude)` - you'll need to look into formatting guides for more detail (you could start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047374/string-formatting-of-a-double))

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this much was incorrect. I will also check into the formatting guides for more help.